# integrate app with native facebook iOS without using an iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ipad

Im wondering if its possible to link my app with the native facebook iphone-app without using iOS at all.

It was pretty easy to create a mobile version and connect it with the m.facebook.com (so it appears in the broswer) through the Developer > Mobile Web URL but it doesnt work/recognize with the native app of facebook.

Is there a way to connect the native iOS FB to my app without creating an app? So it redirects automatically to the browser?

Im trying to avoid to create an iOS app.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If the Application is linked to in news story or post then the App will open in in a browser.

For full integration you'll need a App.

(I don't have a iOS app to test, only pure web app and after posting the apps.facebook.com link to a wall, that link in App opened in the in built web browser).

Comment: hey Barry! Thanks for the reply, but then what you are saying is that only when somebody likes or share something of the app, it will redirect. So if you have the app already installed you will not see it on the left panel, am i right?